# Case insensitive regex for non-English characters

Tags: regex, perl, utf-8

I need to perform a regular expression match on text that includes non-English characters (Spanish, French, German, and Russian).

I want the match to ignore case, so with English characters I would just use the `/i` modifier, but that doesn't work with words like **übermäßig**.

What is the simplest way to write a regex that will match both, say, übermäßig and ÜBERMÄßig? And can the same approach be used to convert upper case non-English letters to their lowercase equivalents in Perl?

Comment: You do know that the correct uppercase version of `übermäßig` is `ÜBERMÄSSIG`, right?

Comment: Actually, no. I don't speak German. Wikipedia seemed to indicate that there is no uppercase letter for ß, but I guess I misunderstood. I just checked if /ß/i matches SS, and it doesn't. Do you know how I can accomplish this?

Comment: There is an uppercase "ß" in Unicode ("ẞ", U+1E9E), but the proper uppercasing of "ß" is "SS" (according to Unicode). In fact, `uc(lc("ẞ"))` returns `SS`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works perfectly fine

```
$ perl -E'use utf8; say "ÜBERMÄẞIG" =~ /^übermäßig\z/i ? "match" : "no match"'
match

$ perl -E'use utf8; say "ÜBERMÄSSIG" =~ /^übermäßig\z/i ? "match" : "no match"'
match
```

(The `use utf8;` says the source code is encoded using UTF-8. It would be impossible to have those characters in the script any other way.)

I suspect an encoding problem, meaning you think you gave Perl "ß" when you didn't. It could also be that you're using an older version of Perl that can't handle multi-char folds correctly. Generally speaking, it could help to use `/u`, but it shouldn't make a difference for this example.

Answer (score 2):

The `/i` modifier works nicely if the strings use Perl's internal encoding.

For example, this prints "yes":

```
perl -le 'use utf8; print "yes" if "ÜBERMäßig" =~ /überMÄßiG/i'
```

The "`use utf8`" tells Perl that my source code is encoded in UTF-8, and therefore Perl decodes all literal strings in my source code from UTF-8 into its internal encoding. This example will not work without `use utf8`.

If your strings come from somewhere else then you may need to apply [`Encode::decode`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Encode.html) -- or tell your source to generate properly decoded strings (e.g. possible with most `DBI` drivers).

Answer (score 1):

If you [set the locale to the appropriate value in your Perl script](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllocale.html), then the `/i` modifier will work on non-English characters--as will other features like regex matching of word boundaries and the `uc` and `lc` functions.

Note that if you need to handle multiple foreign character sets, the linked documentation shows you how to switch locales within your script as needed, using [`setlocale()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllocale.html#The-setlocale-function).

**Edit:** I should have mentioned that this method is deprecated in most cases.  Things should just work with UTF-8.  But it can still be useful sometimes.

Comment: Using locale is archaic and not fully supported. Most systems have extremely broken locales to being with. And it's not needed.

Answer (score 1):

[It works for me.](http://codepad.org/YWfiM5hY) Do you need to `use utf8;`, maybe?

<sub>(Disclaimer: I don't know Perl.)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

```
use locale;
use POSIX qw(locale_h);
setlocale (LC_ALL, $locale{German}) or die "failed to load locale!";
```

Comment: Using locale is archaic and not fully supported. Most systems have extremely broken locales to being with.